ArcMap Layer properties of personal geodatabase: activate field doesn't work
I'm working with a personal GDB in ArcMap. When I go to Layer Properties -> Fields not all fields can be activated. I can set the marker for the field but the attribute table is not updated afterwards.
The personal GDB is used in Access 2016.

What version of ArcMap are you using?  Have you checked the Access database version against the ArcMap System Requirements for the version you are using?

Try to activate the field directly from the attribute table (in the drop down in the top left of the table) by selecting  activate all field, if the fiels still doesn't appear select restore default field width in the same dropdown
